# How can I position my plugin elements (buttons) not in a separate area, but right next to the blender buttons?

Tags: modifiers, interface, add-on

Now i use this code:

class OBJECT_PT_ModifAddPanel(Panel):
bl_label = "Modifier++"
bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
bl_context = "modifier"
bl_category = "Modifier++"

[image]

Comment: What are those buttons? Custom modifiers or what are they doing? The place at the top are not modifiers, but options what to do with modifiers - applying, deleting, changing the visibility and expanding/collapsing the stack. So are your buttons doing something with all modifiers or are they modifiers themselves? If the latter, they don't belong at the top to the other buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top buttons in the Modifier panel are part of the built-in addon `Modifier Tools`. When addon is enabled, it adds a draw function to the panel. See `space_view3d_modifier_tools.py` in BlenderDefault > Blender[Version] > [Version] > scripts > addons - or -
RMB on one of the buttons and click *Edit Source* (if developer extras enabled in preferences)

If a draw function is added to a panel class (append/prepend) there´s an attribute `_draw_funcs` in *class.draw* containing all functions to draw.

```
print("Class:", bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers)
print("Class.draw:" , bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers.draw)
print("Class.draw.draw_funcs:", bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers.draw._draw_funcs)
```

[image]

This we can use to manipulate the displayed items. In script I have copied the addon operators first to keep functionality, then replaced the old draw function with an extended version. Tested in 2.93.7 and 3.3.2

```
import bpy

class TESTOPERATOR_OT_Test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'testoperator.test'
    bl_label = "Test Operator"
    bl_description = "...testing"    

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Testoperator (%s)" % obj.name) # do something       

        return {'FINISHED'} 

def extended_menu(self, context):
    if (context.active_object):
        if (len(context.active_object.modifiers)):
            col = self.layout.column(align=True)

          # original ops
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.operator("object.apply_all_modifiers", icon='IMPORT', text="Apply All")
            row.operator("object.delete_all_modifiers", icon='X', text="Delete All")
 
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.operator("object.toggle_apply_modifiers_view", icon='RESTRICT_VIEW_OFF', text="Viewport Vis")
            row.operator("wm.toggle_all_show_expanded", icon='FULLSCREEN_ENTER', text="Toggle Stack")
                                         
          # custom ops
            row = col.row(align=True)                          
            row.operator(TESTOPERATOR_OT_Test.bl_idname, icon='SNAP_ON', text="Button 1")
            row.operator(TESTOPERATOR_OT_Test.bl_idname, icon='SHADERFX', text="Button 2")  

def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(TESTOPERATOR_OT_Test)

    # check if addon is enabled
    if 'space_view3d_modifier_tools' in bpy.context.preferences.addons.keys(): 

        # get panel
        panel_class = eval("bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers")
        
        # check if 'extended_menu' already in draw_funcs to prevent double entries
        if not [f for f in panel_class.draw._draw_funcs if f.__name__ == 'extended_menu']:

            # add extended menu first (with registered original ops)  
            panel_class.prepend(extended_menu)                                            

            # remove original menu 
            old_menu = [f for f in bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers.draw._draw_funcs if f.__name__ == 'menu'][0]
            panel_class.draw._draw_funcs.remove(old_menu) 
             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]